# wiki: zed_interface/object_stamped link doesn't work

Tags: ros, object-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this page:

http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper

In subsection 4.8 there is a link to zed_interfaces/object_stamped definition that does not work:

http://docs.ros.org/en/api/zed_interfaces/html/msg/object_stamped.html

I would very much appreciate if the said link was repaired.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371169/wiki:-zed_interface/object_stamped-link-doesn%27t-work/) by [burn10](https://answers.ros.org/users/69402/burn10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) on 2021-02-05**:
Sometimes vendors remove resources or docs get edited. We don't have a link checker running on the wiki. Your best bet is to edit the wiki so it points to the correct resource.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-06**:\

> Your best bet is to edit the wiki so it points to the correct resource.

See my answer, that would be impossible in this case.

And @burn10: I do agree with @kscottz: posting here on ROS Answers to request a page on the ROS wiki be updated which is maintained by the `zed-ros-wrapper` maintainers is not the most efficient way to go about it. I'd suggest contacting the maintainers via their issue tracker, or indeed updating the link yourself, if you know the correct one.

The ROS wiki is a wiki after all.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-08**:
Seems you've posted on the issue tracker: [stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper#667](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/issues/667).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not just that link: none of the messages from the `zed_interfaces` package have working ROS msg API links.

It seems the source repository ([stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper.git)) was never registered for indexing by the ROS buildfarm (or at least, it isn't in any of the `distribution.yaml` files for Kinetic, Melodic or Noetic), which means none of the API docs was ever generated.

And even if the package was registered, the link still wouldn't work, as messages use *CamelCase*. It should be `zed_interfaces/ObjectStamped`.

> I would very much appreciate if the said link was repaired.

I would suggest you post an issue on the [zed issue tracker](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/issues), pointing the authors/maintainers to your question on ROS Answers (ie: this one) and the [Indexing Your ROS Repository for Documentation Generation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation) page on the ROS wiki.

But note again: after the maintainers have registered the repository for indexing, the wiki page will have to be updated to use CamelCase everywhere for the messages in the `zed_interfaces` package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1